# Add multiple parameters to IN clause in SQLAPI c++

Tags: c++, sqlapi++

I am using SQLAPI to connect to a SQL-Server database from a C++ code. I need to execute a simple select statement with a IN clause, where the string values in the clause is received as a vector of strings. We want to use parameterised queries so did something like this:

```
std::string getSQLQuery(std::vector<std::string> ids){
    std::stringstream sql;
    sql << "SELECT ID, Name, DOB FROM Employees WHERE ID IN (";
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    for each (auto id in ids)
    {
        sql << ":" << counter + 1;
        if (++counter < ids.size())
        {
            sql << ",";
        }
    }
    sql << ")";
    return sql.str();
}
```

And then,

```
    int param_counter = 0;
    for each (auto id in ids) {
        command.Param(++param_counter).setAsString() = id.c_str();
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't want to undercut your basic question, which I take to be "What's a good way to do this?", but you have some basic syntax problems with your C++. Inferring your intention from the buggy code above, I gather that the goal is to create a command synthesizer with a common SQL select query from an arbitrary set of input id's. Cool. I don't think there's any up-side to first creating a synthesized template command with insertion points and then using their parameter replacement scheme. Might as well do the synthesis all at once. A compile-time-correct version would look something like this (with a few tweaks to make it more reusable) -

```
std::string getSQLQuery(
    const std::string& columns
  , const std::string& table
  , const std::vector<std::string>& ids
){
  // Check for empty strings/arrays here - leads to illegal SQL,
  // so error out or except on empty ids, columns, or "table".

  std::stringstream sql("SELECT ", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
  sql << columns << " FROM " << table << " WHERE ID IN ( ";

  // Trailing commas are not allowed in SQL, which makes synthesis a little trickier.
  // We checked for empty inputs earlier, so we have at least one ID.
  auto iter = ids.begin();
  sql << *iter++;  // add the first (and possibly only) ID
  for (; iter != ids.end(); ++iter) {  // add the rest (if any) with commas
    sql << ", " << *iter;
  }
  sql << " )";   // <- should this be " );"? Or does SQLAPI++ deal with that?
  return sql.str();  // There's a shrink-to-fit method you may want to use here.
}
```

Now you can just do something like -

```
std::vector<std::string> id_array{ "1", "50", "aardvark" };
SACommand basic_command(connection, getSQLQuery("ID, Name, DOB", "Employees", id_array));
basic_command.Execute();
```

This skips the second substitution phase entirely. The SQLAPI++ parameter substitution is intended for queries with a much more rigid template, but you're doing something more dynamic. You can imagine extending this further with input arrays of columns as well, to avoid syntax errors in the table list (like we do in the id list). Also, since id's are often numerical, you could make the id array `std::vector<std::uint64_t>` or whatever fits your specific application. In fact, you can handle both cases with the same body of code by making the signature -

```
template<typename T> std::string getSQLQuery(
    const std::string& columns
  , const std::string& table
  , const std::vector<T>& ids
){
   ... // rest of the implementation is the same
}
```

I'm a new contributor, but a long-time user, so just a word about questions. When you ask a question like, "Can anyone please suggest a better way of doing it?", the answer is always "Yes.". There are a lot of smart people out there and an infinity of solutions to every high-level problem. In the future, you want to state the problem you're trying to solve (not hard to figure out in this case), and if you show a solution that was tried and failed, you should give specifics about how it failed. In the case of the code you put forth, the most obvious reason it failed is that it is syntactically wrong - the compiler would not accept it. "for each" is from some other languages. In C++, it's something like "for (auto id : ids)". But if you were just trying to show some kind of pseudo-code, it suggests that you don't really know if your existing approach works, because it hasn't been tried. And even in that case, you should say what you don't like about the presented solution (like the unnecessary second step of using the SQLAPI++ substitution scheme), and ask specifically if someone can think of a way to remove that. I'm a talker, and I would have given the same response, but for future reference, try to avoid a question that comes down to, "The following code is broken. Someone fix it for me." Just FWIW.

Comment: Hi @cycollins thanks for your quick and detailed response on this topic. Just one small thing, what makes you think I did not provide a minimal working example? First looking at the answer, it really felt weird and angry, but later I realized that the syntax I am using is not a common one. But a valid one nevertheless. I am coming from a C# background, so when I saw the for each loop available in VS, I never thought it might not be a standard feature. But as it turns out, this syntax is not recommended so will be changing this in my code too.

Comment: Just a suggestion, please do validate before accusing, even if it is really silly and stupid. Attaching the msdn article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019

Comment: There were two reasons I was using this type of construct. Firstly to avoid the threat of sql injection. I think the code you displayed can be prone to sql injection attacks, please do comment on this topic. The second reason is optimization of query performance in SQL Server using parameterised queries which is a very commonly used trick. So it would be great if you can suggest something accordingly. +1 for the effort anyway :)

Comment: I genuinely apologize if my tone came off as aggressively critical. I did verify in the sense that I copied your code and attempted to compile. It may be (indeed it seems to be the case) that clang does not accept the non-standard loop keywords, but that VisualStudio does. I'm not unfamiliar with VS, but it was not the environment in which I tried your original code.

Comment: I think I see your point about the SQL injection vulnerability, although (and I'm by no means an SQL security expert), I can't quite see how the two-stage approach (creating a SQLAPI++ command template, then populating it) is not equivalent. I suppose though, the devil's in the implementation details of SQLAPI++. Perhaps they keep the template and the parameters separately and do some last-minute magic to make things tighter. Again, as someone who only occasionally touches programmatic SQL in C++ (oddly enough, I have done it before, but I used a different API), I would defer on that point.

Comment: Well, after sending you through the emotional wringer, I hope there was something substantive that came out of the discussion that was helpful. Again, I am aware this can be rough-and-tumble environment, and I'm still learning the ropes myself.

Comment: Thats witty :) It helped me learn that the syntax is not standard as well...anyway I must change the syntax to the standard c++ way, and raise a issue with VS support to add a flag in the IDE UI to indicate the non-standard nature of it.. regarding the sql part, in the two stage approach, query and the parameters are sent to the database separately so that the database would know the parameters are strictly to be used as parameters only. Thus if you have a id as `'; delete * from employee'`, it would look for a id that is identical to `'; delete * from employee`'.

Comment: On the other hand, with the single query building approach, the same id would have two effects, first part would be a incorrect sql statement till the `;` and second one being a valid sql deleting rows.

Comment: So then just one observation I would make in terms of simplifying the code. Since the replacement points are simply consecutive integers, there's no real reason to iterate through the string vector with the id's in the first stage while creating the template. Might as well just pass in vector.length() and simply count, starting at 1. It won't make that big a difference, but you don't need the actual id values at that point, and depending on how things scale in your application, might help a bit.